# How can I create a new category using Wordpress rest API

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I've searched but I cannot seem to find this one specific answer.
I can successfully create new tags using the below code:

```
<?php
function wpAutoPoster($token,$endpointUrl,$data){
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $endpointUrl,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'accept: application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer '.$token
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
return $response;
}


$jwtAuthToken="xxx";


$endpointUrl="https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/tags";
$data=json_encode(['name'=>'my new tag 1']);

$response=json_decode(wpAutoPoster($jwtAuthToken,$endpointUrl,$data));

var_dump($response);
```

**The above works as expected.**

Now, to create categories, I just change the following 2 lines:

```
$endpointUrl="https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories";
$data=json_encode(['name'=>'my new category 1'])
```

And this is the response I get:

**object(stdClass)#1 (3) { ["code"]=> string(18) "rest_cannot_create" ["message"]=> string(60) "Sorry, you are not allowed to create terms in this taxonomy." ["data"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["status"]=> int(403) }** }

This goes out for my **Custom Post Types** as well.

Setting **'hierarchical' => true** results in the same error.

Answer (score 0):

After much fiddling, I was finally able to make it work by changing the user role to Editor or Administrator on the WordPress admin dashboard.
I hope this will help someone else who is struggling with the same issue.
[image]